# Is it possible to use ActiveStorage without a file input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I haven't seen any documentation on the matter, but to elaborate:

I want to use active storage to upload files in my rails app without having to use a browser's file input element. Whether it be using Drag/Drop, or various custom file pickers, it'd be nice to tell ActiveStorage to upload a file and save it without having to use a file input element.

Also: afaik, it's not allowed to hide a file input and to set it's file contents (as sort of a work around).

Is this possible? Does anyone have an example of how this is done without a file input element?

Comment: Yes you can specified the file explicitly without any file input. Like this `user.avatar.attach(io: File.open("/path/to/face.jpg"), filename: "face.jpg", content_type: "image/jpg")`. Please refer the document. https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activestorage#examples

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ajay, I can't seem to find any documentation that doesn't require a file input for activestorage.js – they all require an input element as seen here: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activestorage#direct-upload-javascript-events

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`DirectUpload`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/javascript/activestorage/direct_upload.js) class for this purpose. Upon receiving a file from your library of choice, instantiate a `DirectUpload` and call its `create` method. `create` takes a callback to invoke when the upload completes:

```
import { DirectUpload } from "activestorage"

// on file selection/drop {
  const url = element.dataset.directUploadUrl
  const upload = new DirectUpload(file, url)

  upload.create((error, blob) => {
    if (error) {
      // Handle the error
    } else {
      // Add an appropriately-named hidden input to the form with a value of blob.signed_id
    }
  })
// }
```

This class is the rare exception to the rule that undocumented Rails APIs are internal. We just haven’t gotten around to documenting it yet.

Comment: How would we do this on the server side? If I am creating the file locally by some script and then I have to upload it to aws s3 to share the link with the client. I can use S3 SDK but then things get messy as I am not experienced.